# Using "a" or not before a disease name

Tags: articles

Which sentence is correct:

He has a poorly controlled diabetes mellitus.

He has poorly controlled diabetes mellitus.

Comment: I'd never come across [diabetes mellitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diabetes_mellitus) before, but apparently it's what nearly everyone just calls ***diabetes***. And we always say *he has diabetes* with no article. On the other hand, we always include the article in *he has **a** cold*, but very rarely include it in *he has cancer*. Each different "disease" has its own particular position somewhere on the ***never*** to ***always*** scale, and I'm not sure there's any learnable rule for usages you don't yet know. Try searching Google Books when in doubt.

Answer (score 1):

We usually **do not use articles before diseases;** the common reasoning is that diseases are not countable nouns. So we say: He has diabetes, pneumonia, arthritis, Crohn's disease, lung cancer, coronary heart disease, etc. ([UNT Dallas](https://www.untdallas.edu/sites/default/files/page_level2/jmd0413/pdf/esl_article_usage_rules.pdf), [English Page](https://www.englishpage.com/articles/advanced-articles.htm)).

There are few **exceptions** from this rule (it's about the usage, not grammar):

- a cold ([English Page](https://www.englishpage.com/articles/advanced-articles.htm))
- the flu, the measles, the mumps, the chicken pox ([UNT Dallas](https://www.untdallas.edu/sites/default/files/page_level2/jmd0413/pdf/esl_article_usage_rules.pdf)).

Comment: Not sure about AmE but, in the UK, I would actively discourage "the chicken pox"; my niece just got chickenpox.

Answer (score 1):

I would treat

> He has a poorly controlled diabetes mellitus.

as an elided form of

He has a poorly controlled **case of** diabetes mellitus.

( by the way "mellitus" derives from "mel", a now obsolete word for honey, surviving in mellifluous (honey-spoken)  and a few other words, because urine is sweet in advance cases of diabetes. "milk and mel" was once the usual term for "milk and honey".)

"A cancer" may be used to emphasize one of a group of possible forms of cancer.

One speaks of "a heart condition" but "heart disease"

Answer (score 0):

The noun **diabetes** is uncountable, so I guess we should write

> He has poorly controlled diabetes mellitus.

We only can use the indefinite article with countable singular nouns.

I found a couple of "has **a** poorly controlled diabetes" in Google Books, but instances of "has poorly controlled diabetes" were more numerous.

Comment: It follows the same pattern as "an impeccable English".

Comment: A few older people still say *He has **the** flu*, but mostly that *definite* article usage has died out. Same with *He has **the** measles*. But I'd say it's about 50-50 with *He has [an] earache.*

Comment: I have heard British (and British-trained) doctors use indefinite articles before names of conditions. They used to be criticised for referring to patients by their condition, e.g. "the myasthenia gravis in bed 6", but I hear they are training new ones not to do that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've always heard and said *the flu*. It has nothing to do with the age of anybody. Honestly, I've never heard it said *without* the definite article. Possibly, this is a regional thing and I'm influenced by US English more than UK in this case.

Comment: Using a definite article before a disease (the flu, the mumps, the measles) was widespread in Britain, especially among working class people, up to around 100 years ago, but has been declining since then.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Apparently there's quite a big US/UK split here - particularly over the last 50 years. NGrams  [AmE corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+flu%2Cgot+the+flu&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20flu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20the%20flu%3B%2Cc0) has ***got the flu*** being 6-7 times more common than ***got flu***, but they're about equal in BrE - which I see as consistent with the article-less version actually being *more* common in BrE ***speech*** (NGrams being ***written*** instances).

Comment: ...I also note that AmE remains firmly wedded to the article with ***got the mumps / measles***, whereas [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+mumps%2Cgot+the+mumps%2Cgot+measles%2Cgot+the+measles&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20mumps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20the%20mumps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20measles%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20the%20measles%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows that even in the (more dated/formal?) *written* form, the article-less versions are now much more common in BrE.

Comment: You get "the flu" because "the flu" usually *isn't* "the flu", and everyone you work with *knows* it!  If you *really* got the flu, you'd actually have got influenza; you don't get "the influenza"!  But, this is about diabetes, and you certainly don't get "the diabetes"...